# How to prompt a user for information twice in Linux?

Tags: linux, verification

In Linux (Debian/CentOS) I want the user to verify his input.

```shell
read email_address
```

This doesn't include verification and the [manual of read](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) doesn't include any chapter about verification.

How to verify the data?

Comment: Read twice and compare. Can you take it from here? Have you tried to implement this? Or are you hoping for a tool that supports this out of the box?

Comment: How to use `read` twice for the same input? I am not sure I would prefer a tool doing this out of box because I would prefer a more "simple but longer" way. Something more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked to describes the `read` builtin of Bash. In other shells `read` may support less options, different options. POSIX `read` is documented [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html).

To prompt a user for information twice, use `read` twice. To check if the responses match, compare them as strings. A portable and basic example:

```sh
printf 'E-mail: '
read input1
printf 'Confirm e-mail: '
read input2
if [ "$input1" = "$input2" ]; then
   echo Match.
else
   echo Mismatch.
fi
```

A more advanced example for Bash:

```bash
IFS= read -r -p 'E-mail: ' input1 \
&& IFS= read -r -p 'Confirm e-mail: ' input2 \
&& if [ "$input1" = "$input2" ]; then
   echo Match.
else
   echo Mismatch.
fi
```

Advancements applied:

- `-p` (non-portable though).
- [`IFS= read -r …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618).
- Chaining the commands with `&&`; this way the `if … fi` block will be executed if and only if both `read`s succeed.

Other notes:

- In Bash you can use `read -e` that will use Readline and its quite advanced line editing. Without this option the line discipline should at least react to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, so the user can still correct his or her mistakes and review the input before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Prompting twice makes more sense with (Bash's) `read -s` that suppresses echoing and thus makes it hard to correct mistakes. This mode is useful when asking for a password or so.
- The code snippets in this answers only verify if one string matches the other. Checking if a string is a valid e-mail address is a separate ([and non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/10765659)) task.